# Запуск распознавания речи из спящего режима

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

Необходимо запустить последовательность распознавания речи из спящего режима. То есть, я активирую распознавание речи, блокирую экран, а оно запускается в фоне и распознает то, что я говорю. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: точно так же, как и не в спящем режиме, только не давать устройству засыпать (`WakeLock`)